# Do I capitalize appellant courts?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

**Sentence: Appeals are reviewed by the United States appellant courts.**
What else needs to be capitalized in this sentence? Should Appellant be capitalized or lowercased?

Comment: Is it actually "appelate", rather than "appellant"? And, what is the source of the sentence?

Comment: Google **capital letters** and read some of the guidance re their use. Then tell us what you think.

Answer (score 0):

I think that that appellant court should be lowercased because it is not the true name of a court. The true name of the appellant court is court of appeals or for example Maryland Six Circuit Court of Appeals.  Appellant appears to be an adjective so I would lowercase appellant....am I right? It is like saying United States trial courts or United States appellant court. answered by rcorn**strong text**